# Template for new ASP.NET Core Razorpage in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Starting to work with a web app and following the steps here to use razor pages

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/

Is there a template (either in VS or elsewhere) for adding a new razorpage (ie the cshtml and the cshtml.cs files)? As a workaround I created an MVC View page (with the .cshtml ext) and then created a .cs file and renamed it to match the naming pattern.

I'm having problems running the scaffolding as well but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 just by using `Add New Item` and choosing `Razor Page`.

You can also use `dotnet new`. For example:

```
dotnet new page --name MyPage
```

See the documentation for [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x). You can always get started by just running `dotnet new` alone to see the available templates.

Comment: I have the latest version of VS and Razor Page is not an option in the Add New Item dialog. Only thing razor is "Razor Tag Helper". The cmd line option works so I will use that for now. Thanks

Comment: That's odd. If I create a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in VS 2017 (15.3), I see the Razor Page option if I'm targeting .NET Core. I've noticed that it's missing if I use .NET Framework 4.6.x though.

Comment: I'm targeting net47 so that explains why I didn't see it and you did.